# How to choose one smallest values among multiple duplicates values in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Sample Data:**

```
       Fitness Value    MSU Locations    MSU Range
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
```

**Sample Code 1**

```
WATT1 = WATTx.loc[WATTx['Fitness Value'].eq(df['Fitness Value'].min())]
WATT1
```

**Sample Code 2**

```
WATTy = WATTx .loc[WATTx ['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]
WATTy
```

**Output:**

```
       Fitness Value    MSU Locations    MSU Range
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
13       1.045426        {13, 38, 15}    2.213424
```

Since all values are the same. In the output, it prints all the values. That's the issue.

I want to print one smallest value among these duplicate values. **Is it possible?**

**#Screenshot 1**

[image]

**#Screenshot 2**
[image]

**Full Error Track**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py:391, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    390 try:
--> 391     return self._range.index(new_key)
    392 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 13 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [59], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 WATTy= WATTx.reset_index().loc[WATTx['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]
      2 display (WATTy)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1073, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1070 axis = self.axis or 0
   1072 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1073 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1312, in _LocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1310 # fall thru to straight lookup
   1311 self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1312 return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1260, in _LocIndexer._get_label(self, label, axis)
   1258 def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1259     # GH#5567 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1260     return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:4056, in NDFrame.xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   4054             new_index = index[loc]
   4055 else:
-> 4056     loc = index.get_loc(key)
   4058     if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):
   4059         if loc.dtype == np.bool_:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py:393, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    391         return self._range.index(new_key)
    392     except ValueError as err:
--> 393         raise KeyError(key) from err
    394 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    395 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 13
```

Comment: Am I missing something or your expected output is an exact copy of your input ?

Comment: @abokey That's funny, actually. Since all values are the same. In the output, it prints all the values. That's the issue.

Comment: What's your expected output based on sample data you shared ?

Comment: @abokey Yes. I have a list of values where there are multiple similar values (smallest duplicates)

Comment: _I want to print one smallest value among these duplicate values_ For you, what would be this value based on the example you gave ?

Comment: @abokey Since all values are the same. so anyone of these will work. One way is to drop duplicates. However, I wonder if there is any way to solve it using a built-in function (`.min()`).

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` is in fact a _built-in_ function.

Comment: @abokey I mean a built-in function which works with `.min()`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your dataframe `WATTx` has a non unique index values.

Try to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before using boolean indexing with [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) :

```
WATTy= WATTx.reset_index().loc[WATTx['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(WATTy)

idx                       1
Fitness Value      1.045426
MSU Locations    {13,38,15}
MSU Range          2.213424
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting this `error`.

Comment: `ValueError: 13 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [49], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 a = WATTx.reset_index().loc[WATTx['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]
      2 a`

Comment: `13` is a common index for all values.

Comment: If your're working on a notebook, can you give a screenshot of `display(WATTx)` ?

Comment: I just added a screenshot. You can find it at the end of the question.

Comment: I also added the screenshot according to your answer with an error track.